# How to generate an array with all possible combinations grouping adjacent elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

Given an array of elements, I want a function that returns all the possible combinations, grouping adjacent elements.

Input: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Expected output:

```
[
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [[1, 2], 3, 4, 5],
    [[1, 2], [3, 4], 5],
    [[1, 2], 3, [4, 5]],
    [1, [2, 3], 4, 5],
    [1, [2, 3], [4, 5]],
    [1, 2, [3, 4], 5],
    [1, 2, 3, [4, 5]]
]
```

Comment: Please show us what you tried so far.

Comment: What is holding you back to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with a recursive generator. The idea is to:

- get the results for the array without the first element, and then prefix that first element to the results
- get the result for the array without the first pair, and then prefix that pair as subarray to the results

```js
function* partition(arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) return yield arr;
    for (const result of partition(arr.slice(1))) {
        yield arr.slice(0, 1).concat(result);
    }
    for (const result of partition(arr.slice(2))) {
        yield [arr.slice(0, 2)].concat(result);
    }
}


const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
console.log(Array.from(partition(arr)));
```